# Syntax error on async function as object field

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, feathersjs

I'm have a problem on the simple [Getting started](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/basics/starting.html#in-the-browser) tutorial of FeathersJS.

I copy/past both code and run the server, but it return me a Syntax Error on `client.js line 5`:

```
app.use('todos', {
  async get(name) {
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  >  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

What did I miss ?

---

**EDIT:** I forgot to say that error come from the browser after I run
`http-server public/`

Comment: What node.js version are you using, does it support `async function`s?

Comment: You need `node 8` or greater to have `async function` support

Comment: `nodejs --version` give me v4.2.6 but `n ls` give me the v10.6.0 (like `node --version`). I'm confused, it's client side, how node does affect this ?!

Comment: I purge nodejs, and I have now only node 10.6.0 but it's still not working..

Comment: Syntax error in browser? What browser/version?

Comment: Chrome version 54 64bits

Comment: `async/await` is enabled by default in Chrome 55+ (see https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5643236399906816) - the current version is 67+ so you should update your browser.